# How can I publish the vscode plugin in vscode marketplace using API?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

My goal is to publish a extension in vscode marketplace without manually interact. Can someone make me aware, whether I can use extension API for this or there is another way using curl option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [vsce](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-vsce) CLI. With this you can publish and update an extension from command line. Therefore you should be capable to automate that process in a CI/CD pipeline. There is also [an article in the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension) that explains how to use the tool.

Optionally, you can take a look to [one of my extensions](https://github.com/HaaLeo/vscode-timing). There I automatically create releases using azure pipelines.

Comment: Yes I used vsce CLI for publishing the extension. But In here I was unable to get the clear idea regarding the extension API yet. Thank you , I will look into CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: [This section](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/continuous-integration#automated-publishing) should explain exactly what you need.